# What are the Difference standards followed in multiple domains in App'n Development?

Tags: java, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am interested to know , are there any specific set of standards followed while implementing a Web Application using Dot Net,Java,MVC (as matter of fact any technology) in different **domains** like Health, Business, Logistics, etc.

Being a developer we can code irrespective of any domain with the skill set we have but what is the Domain experience achieved while developing an application.

PS:This post may be vague and may get closed down but I believe if there is a real difference in implementations it can be hell lot helpful further.

Comment: This is not a .NET specific problem.  Each industry, be it aerospace, medical, etc, will have published coding standards, guidelines and minimum technical and process requirements that you would have to follow in order to meet the intent of that industry's standards / have your application be allowed to operate within that industry.

Comment: @Tommy agreed (as i even mentioned in my post)  but i'm keen to know those standards anywhere documented .